# How to make running exe active after hiding taskbar programmatically c#

Tags: c#-2.0

I need to close an exe using alt+f4.
1. While running exe, user can able to save the screenshots by pressing PrintScreen at that time taskbar is made hidden.
2. After saving taskbar is shown.
3. Immediately after saving, user needs to close the exe file by Alt+f4 key press but the control goes to the windows and shows shutdown window

The exe need to get close after saving screen shots

Here is the code which is implemented.

```
private void GuiPane_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
 try
{
 if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.PrintScreen))
  {
    Taskbar.Hide();
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;
    using ( bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
     {
     using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
     {
     g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
      }
     SaveImage(bitmap);
     }
     Taskbar.Show();
    }
  }
catch (Exception)
{
 throw;
 }
}

public class Taskbar

        {

                [DllImport("user32.dll")]
                private static extern int FindWindow(string className, string windowText);

                [DllImport("user32.dll")]
                private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int command);

                [DllImport("user32.dll")]
                public static extern int FindWindowEx(int parentHandle, int childAfter, string className, int windowTitle);

                [DllImport("user32.dll")]
                private static extern int GetDesktopWindow();

                private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
                private const int SW_SHOW = 1;

                protected static int Handle
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
                    }
                }

                protected static int HandleOfStartButton
                {
                    get
                    {
                        int handleOfDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
                        int handleOfStartButton = FindWindowEx(handleOfDesktop, 0, "button", 0);
                        return handleOfStartButton;
                    }
                }

                private Taskbar()
                {
                    // hide ctor
                }

                public static void Show()
                {
                    ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOW);
                    ShowWindow(HandleOfStartButton, SW_SHOW);
                }

                public static void Hide()
                {
                    ShowWindow(Handle, SW_HIDE);
                    ShowWindow(HandleOfStartButton, SW_HIDE);
                }
            }
```